# ExecJS::RuntimeError <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I am trying to add infinite scroll to my rails application using the `will_paginate` gem and then using AJAX to fetch the next paginated page, but my javascript is not being rendered.

It seems like turbolinks is causing the problem. When I remove turbolinks the error goes away, but the script no longer runs. Below are my logs and script. Can anyone help me out?

This is the error I get from my logs:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (SyntaxError: [stdin]:5:2: unexpected if):
     5:   <!-- had to add the script to override JS error -->
     6:   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
     7:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
     8:   <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
     9:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    10: </head>
    11: <body>
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___2390735874352053488_70114430886900'
```

My links.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->

$(window).scroll ->
    console.log('working')
    if $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50
    alert('next page')
```

Now if I take out the part of the script that compares the scroll placement to the doc height and window height the code works.

```
jQuery ->

$(window).scroll ->
    console.log('working')
```

If you need to see any other information I'd be happy to provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like indentation issues to me.  Coffeescript is whitespace sensitive.  Try

```
jQuery ->
  $(window).scroll ->
    if $(window).scrollTop() > ($(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50)
      alert('next page')
```

The differences here are

- indent `scroll` method call into the `jQuery` onReady function.
- indent `alert` under the `if`

As for the turbolinks issue, you can't simply use `jQuery ->` (the onReady shortcut) to get everything to load.  You probably need to add another listener.

So instead of:

```
jQuery ->
  $(window).scroll ->
    ...
```

You might try something like this:

```
onPageReady = ->
  $(window).scroll ->
    if ...

$(document).ready(onPageReady)
$(document).on('page:load', onPageReady)
```

Very much like described here: [Rails 4: how to use $(document).ready() with turbo-links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770517/rails-4-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links)

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Are you familiar with why I might be getting this error when trying to make an ajax request 'xhr.send( ( options.hasContent && options.data ) || null );'

Comment: Updated the answer to include some more info about turbolinks and onReady.  check that out and see if that helps